# WCF callback not invoked on the client-side and hangs on the server-side

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, callback

I have a WCF service which works absolutely fine with regards to regular client->server calls. However I have attempted to introduce a simple callback into the service but it is not working... ultimately I am not sure where I have gone wrong so let me show you the set up and tell you what I do know.

1) Contracts

```
public interface IPIRSCallbackService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void OnCallback();
}

[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IPIRSCallbackService))]
public interface IPIRSService
{ etc...
```

2) Server Contract Implementation

NOTE: I check the state of callback channel and it is "opened" - not sure how much this is worth though.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)]
class PIRSService : IPIRSService
{

    public PIRSService()
    {
        callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPIRSCallbackService>();
        var x = ((ICommunicationObject)callback).State;
        callback.OnCallback(); // HANGS HERE
    }
    etc.
```

3) Client - creating the proxy

Now, this is probably not the common way you will see because I am using a ViewModelLocator to inject the service into my viewmodels... but I am sure this isn't causing the problem... and note that the normal service calls work absolutely fine.

ViewModelLocator registering the service instances

```
       SimpleIoc.Default.Register<PIRSService>(() =>
            {
                IPIRSCallbackService callback = new PIRSCallbackService(); 
                InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);
                return new PIRSService(context, "PIRSClient");
            }, true);

       SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IPIRSService>(() => 
            {
                return SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<PIRSService>();
            }, true);
```

4) Connecting to the service

```
    DuplexChannelFactory<IPIRSService> channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IPIRSService>(callbackContext, endpointConfigName);
    channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = userName;
    channelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
    proxy = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    ((IClientChannel)proxy).Open();
```

5) Client - endpoint configuration

```
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:20437/PIRSService" binding="netTcpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="StandardNetTcpBinding" contract="PIRS_Common.Service.IPIRSService"
    name="PIRSClient" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" behaviorConfiguration="CustomBehavior">
    <identity>
      <dns value="WCfServer" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
```

So, I don't know why the client-side implementation of the callback contract isn't fired... and consequently the server side call to the callback method hangs on the calls... as it is waiting for the callback to be completed. I am sure it is an issue with the callback not being registered correctly... but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Do I need to register the call back contract on the client-side endpoint or anywhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may to make sure that you add "ConcurrencyMode.Multiple" to the "CallbackBehavior" attribute on the class that implements the callback.

```
[CallbackBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

Callback ConcurrencyMode reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsnotes/archive/2013/09/18/wcf-callback-operations-are-invoked-sequentially.aspx

In addition, if you have not already, you may want to consider enabling WCF tracing to ensure the server is really calling the client callback method.

WCF Tracing reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your pointer! I have enabled tracing on the client-side and server-side and it is logged that the server sends the callback and the client receives the callback request... and nothing else is logged after that point! I have no idea what is going on, as I am sure the connection must be established correctly for the message to have been sent to the client... but why is the contract method not being fired? Would it be useful if I post the logs? As I may be missing something!

Comment: Interestingly... the callback request is processed on the client-side, but it doesn't reach the point of actually executing the request... not sure which this doesn't happen though! The last stage logged within the activity is "The security protocol verified the incoming message"... I know this might seem like it is a security issue... but the statement does imply that the message was verified successfully! But to be honest I'm not sure where to go with this now... any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’m not sure where the issue is, so perhaps you could confirm or correct the following, simple process flow statement:  client --> server --> callback -ERROR-> client

Comment: I would say it is more like client --> server --> callback --> client -ERROR , the reason I would say the error is after the client is because the client does receive the callback request, but doesn't process it correctly/actually call the callback method implementation! I have posted another question regarding the trace logs... please have a look if you have time (much appreciated) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018450/wcf-callback-not-executed

Comment: So, to clarify, the client successfully calls the service and the service successfully calls back to the client. If that is correct, I'm confused about the issue / missing functionality.

Comment: The client calls the service, the service then makes a callback to the client, the client receives the callback request, at which point the implementation of the method should be called right? then the server would receive the response to say the callback has been completed and it would continue to execute the clients initial service request. However, the implementation of the callback method is never called on the client-side, so there is never a response back to the server, so everything just hangs and eventually times out. Please ask for clarification on anything that I am not making clear.

Comment: Interesting, the following article might be helpful ... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsnotes/archive/2013/09/18/wcf-callback-operations-are-invoked-sequentially.aspx

Comment: any luck determining the cause/solution?

Comment: Yes, sorry, haven't had chance to post the answer yet but will do so today! Basically I am self-hosting within a WPF application and the initial call is made on the main UI thread, and I assumed callbacks would be handled on a seperate thread, but by default they are not! So, you just have to set the Concurrency mode on the actual callback implementation! Feel a bit silly for not noticing that haha! But no tutorials I have seen require this on the callback implementation! So will leave an answer to hopefully help anyone else that makes my mistake!

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the benefits of our comments and the fact that setting the concurrency mode fixed the issue. Regards.